# Checking button text in PHP, sending value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have different dropdown menu in a search bar:

```
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdown1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                    {tmpl_var name='defaultValue'}
                    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

Don't worry about vlibTemplate tag. It works, the problem appears when I send this value with Ajax to PHP. I take the value with:

```
values['value1']=$( "#dropdown1" ).text();
values['value2']=$( "#dropdown2" ).text();
```

In PHP page I can see all values sended (and they appear!) but control like this doesn't work:

```
if ($value1=='default' && $value2=='default') {
        //other commands
}
```

I worried about span element in HTML. It can cause some problems? Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you setting `$value1` and `$value2` ?

Comment: is that possible to set button's `data-attr` instead of `text`?

Comment: I set the php variable from the $_POST @Epodax

Comment: @Epodax yes, the name is correct. I try print_r function for $_POST and some echo funcionts for testing if the values are correct. They are. The problem appear if I controll if some of them is equal to my default value (but they are equals!)

Comment: why not add the caret using `:after` css rather than having a physical span?

Comment: It works if I use data-attribute and not the text. Thanks @vijayP

Comment: Glad to know it...welcome @user4810476... `:)`!